# Python optparse: how to make a repeatable group of options?

Tags: python, optparse

Here is a simplified view of the script I am programming in python:

- The script is used to compare two files.
- The type (local or remote) of each file must be specified (***mandatory***)
- For a local file:

  - Its filename must be specified (***mandatory***)
  - Its path can be specified (***optional***, default is `.`)
- For a remote file:

  - Its filename must be specified (***mandatory***)
  - Its path must be specified (***mandatory***)
  - An boolean flag can be specified (***optional***)

So I would like to use it like this:

```
compare.py -L local.txt -L local2.txt -p /tmp/
```

or

```
compare.py -L local.txt -R remote.txt -p remoteDir/ --myFlag
```

So I need to define 2 groups of options (local/L and remote/R), each containing its own set of mandatory and optional options.

I have not found a way to achieve this with `optparse` (or even `argparse`, but I'd like to stick with `optparse` if possible as I'm writing the script for Python 2.6.7)

Is there any clean solution ?

Comment: Would it not be easier to simply use -L x.txt,y.txt instead of using -L twice ?

Comment: @pypat, I still don't see how I could handle the optional option that comes with -L, apart from using some ugly `compare.py -L x.txt,y.txt -p ,/tmp/`

Comment: And using `,` as a separator means that file names with commas in them pose a problem.

Comment: @Alfe You are right though I do not consider it an issue (I know that the filenames will never have 'dangerous' characters).

Comment: `argparse` is MUCH better than `optparse`. You can still use Python 2.6.x if you install this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with [option callbacks](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse-option-callbacks) + helper object which traces context of the current option. Example:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

class FileBase(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.path = None
class LocalFile(FileBase):
    pass
class RemoteFile(FileBase):
    pass

class FileOptionParser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_file = None
        self.files = []

    def set_path(self, option, opt, value, parser):
        self.last_file.path = value

    def set_file(self, option, opt, value, parser):
        if   option.dest=="local" : cls = LocalFile
        elif option.dest=="remote": cls = RemoteFile
        else:                       assert False
        self.last_file = cls(value)
        self.files.append(self.last_file)
        setattr(parser.values, option.dest, self.last_file)

fop = FileOptionParser()

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-L', '--local',  type='string', action='callback', callback=fop.set_file)
parser.add_option('-R', '--remote', type='string', action='callback', callback=fop.set_file)
parser.add_option('-p', '--path',   type='string', action='callback', callback=fop.set_path)

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
print [(f.fname, f.path) for f in fop.files]
```

example is:

```
> python test.py -L local.txt -R remote.txt -p remoteDir/
[('local.txt', None), ('remote.txt', 'remoteDir/')]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to implement this prototype! It definitely looks like it suits my needs.

Comment: No problem :), it didn't take much time (I was eager to check if the idea I had could be implemented).

Comment: I still don't understand why you wrote `setattr(parser.values, option.dest, self.last_file)` ?

Comment: Although it doesn't make much sense for repeatable arguments (rep.option values will be overwritten), I did it just to leave default optparse callback implementation style.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that you are not talking about *options* anymore but about *arguments* to your program.  *Options* are modifiers which (optionally) can be given to influence the behavior of your program; *arguments* on the other side are the input data the program shall work on (additional to `stdin` in some cases).

Having that said, I think you should make your optional boolean flag an option and all other information arguments to be parsed after `optparse` has done its work.  Figure out a neat syntax to specify what argument specifies a local file and what specifies a remote file, e. g. `/path/to/local/file` and `host:/path/to/remote/file` (although this syntax is used by things like `rsync`, keep in mind that it has problems with colons `:` in path names).

Comment: I have to disagree with your definition of an 'option'. As per http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html, 'options' are not only modifiers as they can be followed by an 'option argument' that carries actual input data.  As for the approach you suggest,

Comment: [end of previous comment:] I don't believe it solves the issue of dealing with cases where the path is not specified.

Comment: With 'modifiers' I never implied they couldn't take arguments.  It's more a semantical distinction.  The name *option* implies that it is *optional*, i. e. can be present or absent.  In case the value must be given, I find it wrong to use an *option* for it.  In this case, it is an argument.  But I'm well aware that this view is not clearly followed in CLIs.